# How I fetching value from XML with grouping conditions?

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to fetching attribute value from XML with some conditions. I did not know how the group of values check in XPATH condition.

Below is my XML format:

```
<TTIDCData>
   <CYAccountHide HideTable="False">
      <fldAccountType Value="55" HideField="False" PrintValue="55" Description=""/>
      <fldActNumber Value="502100" HideField="False" PrintValue="502100"/>
   </CYAccountHide>
   <CYAccountHide HideTable="False">
      <fldAccountType Value="55" HideField="False" PrintValue="55" Description=""/>
      <fldActNumber Value="502200" HideField="False" PrintValue="502200"/>
   </CYAccountHide>
   <CYAccountHide HideTable="False">
      <fldAccountType Value="55" HideField="False" PrintValue="55" Description=""/>
      <fldActNumber Value="502200" HideField="False" PrintValue="502200"/>
   </CYAccountHide>
   <CYAccountHide HideTable="False">
      <fldAccountType Value="55" HideField="False" PrintValue="55" Description=""/>
      <fldActNumber Value="502222" HideField="False" PrintValue="502200"/>
   </CYAccountHide>
   <person name="blair" address="502100"/>
   <person name="blair" address="502200"/>
   <person name="blair" address="502205"/>
   <person name="blair" address="502200"/>
</TTIDCData>
```

I want to value which is not match. Conditions is `//CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value != //person/@address`

But that condition does not work.

Basically in my XML I have a value for `//CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value` this attribute is `502100,502200,502201` and for `//person/@address` attribute have value is `502100,502200`. And I want to value with help of xpath is only `502201`

If verify only one value then //CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value != '502100' this condition is work but I want verify group of value with that XML tag.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is "the group of values check in XPATH condition"? Showing your _expected result_ (what the XPath expression should return) would help.

Comment: My question was how I get different value from compare with CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value this path and person/@address.. Both path return some value but I need different(not equal to) value..

Comment: "Showing your expected result (what the XPath expression should return) would help".

Comment: 502201 value return by XPath...

Comment: i update XML, in that case only return that value which is under //CYAccountHide tag but i want all miss match value in both side. Not needed only one side miss match value.

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. Again, please show the output you expect with the updated XML input. Also, say in what way exactly the answer I have given below does _not_ work. It does return `502222` for the new input - is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect with my requirement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have understood what you need now. Use the following XPath expression

```
//CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value[not(. = //person/@address)]
```

which translates to

```
//CYAccountHide/fldActNumber/@Value       Select all attributes named "Value" of
                                          elements "fldActNumber" that themselves are
                                          children of "CYAccountHide" elements.
[not(. = //person/@address)]              but only return them if there is no "person"
                                          element anywhere in the document that has an
                                          "address" attribute with the same value as
                                          the "Value" attribute.
```

and the result will be

```
Value="502201"
```